# 18.04 How to disable "Select your audio device" dialog when plugging a device

Tags: sound

The question is simple. How can I disable this annoying menu that pop out every time I plug my headphone?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1spw.png

I'm plugging-in an headset, not a spaceship. It should recognize it without prompt from my side.

Thank you,